# Continuation of an asymptotic series originally defined for $z>0$ to $z<0$

Tags: soft-question, asymptotics, power-series, gamma-function, divergent-series

Consider the well-known [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) of the $\Gamma%$-function:
$$\Gamma(x)\sim\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi }{x}}\left[1+\frac{1}{12 x}+\frac{1}{288 x^2}-\frac{139}{51840 x^3}-\frac{571}{2488320 x^4}+\dots\right].\tag1$$
The series in the square brackets does not converge, but by truncating it, we can get an approximation that works pretty well for large $x$. Let's perform a change of variable $x=1/z$ and regroup factors. Now we have:
$$\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac1z\right)(z\,e)^{1/z} }{\sqrt{2 \pi  z}}\sim1+\frac{z}{12}+\frac{z^2}{288}-\frac{139 z^3}{51840}-\frac{571 z^4}{2488320}+\dots\tag2$$
Again, the series on the right does not converge for $z>0$. Now, I am stepping out of the rigorous realm into dangerous territory, but let's explore it and say that this series in some sense (that you, hopefully, will help me to figure out) *represents* the function on the left. If we plot both the function on the left and a truncated version of the series on the right (a polynomial), we will see that their graphs almost coincide for small positive $z$. If we extend the plot into negative $z$, then the polynomial (naturally) continues smoothly, but the function takes heavily oscillating complex values (not shown on the plot).
[image: plot]

---

*Question:* Does the divergent series on the right of $(2)$ *represent* any smooth real-valued function for $z<0$ in the same sense as it *represents* the left side of $(2)$ for $z>0$? If yes, then what is that function? Does it have an explicit expression in terms of the $\Gamma$-function?

I understand that my question is vague and I apologize for that. I hope it makes some sense.

Comment: The short answer is $$
\frac{{\sqrt {2\pi z} }}{{\Gamma (1/z)(ze)^{1/z} }}.
$$ Look at my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us define the *scaled gamma function* via
$$
\Gamma ^ *  (z) = \frac{{\Gamma (z)}}{{\sqrt {2\pi } z^{z - 1/2} \mathrm{e}^{ - z} }}.
$$
It is known that
$$
\Gamma ^ *  (z) \sim \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{\gamma _n }}{{z^n }}} = 1 + \frac{1}{{12z}} + \frac{1}{{288z^2 }} - \frac{{139}}{{51840z^3 }} -  \cdots 
$$
as $|z|\to +\infty$, $|\arg z|<\pi$, and $\gamma_n$ denote the so-called Stirling coefficients. It is also known that
$$
\log \Gamma ^ *  (z) \sim \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{B_{2k} }}{{2k(2k - 1)z^{2k - 1} }}} 
$$
as $|z|\to +\infty$, $|\arg z|<\pi$, and $B_k$ denote the Bernoulli numbers. Consequently, we have the formal identity
$$
\exp \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{B_{2k} }}{{2k(2k - 1)}}x^{2k - 1} } } \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \gamma _n x^n } .
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\gamma _n x^n } & = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \gamma _n ( - x)^n }  = \exp \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{B_{2k} }}{{2k(2k - 1)}}( - x)^{2k - 1} } } \right)
\\ & = \exp \left( { - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{B_{2k} }}{{2k(2k - 1)}}x^{2k - 1} } } \right) = \left(\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \gamma _n x^n } \right)^{-1}.
\end{align*}
In other words,
$$
\frac{1}{\Gamma ^ *  (z)} \sim \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  { \frac{{\gamma _n }}{{z^n }}} = 1 - \frac{1}{{12z}} + \frac{1}{{288z^2 }} + \frac{{139}}{{51840z^3 }} -  \cdots 
$$
as $|z|\to +\infty$, $|\arg z|<\pi$.

Comment: Interesting! So, by changing the sign of the variable, we get the reciprocal series. This is unique for the $\Gamma$-function, right? How would I deal with an asymptotic expansion for another function, say, Barnes $G$-function?

Comment: See my revised answer.